# Migrate lib from old Nx workspace (without project.json) to new Nx workspace

Tags: angular, monorepo, nrwl-nx, multi-project, nx-workspace

I have a lib created in a Nx workspace that I started with very old version (can't remember which one). The lib has the following file and folder structure:

[image]

Now, in a new Nx workspace for new lib I have the following structure:

[image]

As you can see new version has **project.json** and no **ng-package.json** nor **package.json**.

So, how can I upgrade this lib to fit the new Nx workspace?

I have tried to run `nx g @nrwl/workspace:convert-to-nx-project my-lib`

but I get this error: **Cannot find configuration for 'my-lib'**

I tried to run `nx g @nrwl/workspace:convert-to-nx-project --all` but it seems it can't find it:

```
Skipping my-app since apps/my-app/project.json already exists.
Skipping my-app-e2e since apps/my-app-e2e/project.json already exists.
Skipping my-new-lib since libs/my-new-lib/project.json already exists.
```

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: If you add --buildable=true when creating a new library both `ng-package.json` and `package.json` will be created. I'd personally create a new library in your new workspace and copy the files across

Comment: 1. you have to check the name of libs inside nx.json file
2. maybe the nx version that you had installed globally it's different respect the inner one and can create some . Sometime it's better add "nx:nx" in scripts section of package.json and run the nx command with npm run nx -- g @nrwl/workspace:convert-to-nx-project --all